# Matlab process termination in slurm

Tags: matlab, slurm

I have two questions that to me seem related:

First, is it necessary to explicitly terminate Matlab in my sbatch command? I have looked through several online slurm tutorials, and in some cases the authors include an exit command:

http://www.umbc.edu/hpcf/resources-tara-2013/how-to-run-matlab.html

And in some they don't:

http://www.buffalo.edu/ccr/support/software-resources/compilers-programming-languages/matlab/PCT.html

Second, when creating a parallel pool in a job, I almost always get the following warning:

*Warning: Found 4 pre-existing communicating job(s) created by pool that are
running, and 2 communicating job(s) that are pending or queued. You can use
'delete(myCluster.Jobs)' to remove all jobs created with profile local. To
create 'myCluster' use 'myCluster = parcluster('local')'*

Why is this happening, and is there any way to avoid it happening to myself and to others because of me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you launch Matlab. Note that your two examples use distinct methods for running a matlab script; the first one uses the `-r` option

```
matlab -nodisplay -r "matrixmultiply, exit"
```

while the second one uses stdin redirection from a file

```
matlab < runjob.m
```

In the first solution, the Matlab process will be left running after the script is finished, that is why the `exit` command is needed there. In the second solution, the Matlab process is terminated as `stdin` closes when the end of the file is reached.

If you do not end the matlab process, Slurm will kill it when the maximum allocation time is reached, as defined by the `--time` option in you submission script or by the default cluster (or partition) value.

To avoid the warning you mention, make sure to systematically use `matlabpool close` at the end of your job. If you have several instances of Matlab running on the same node, and you have a shared home directory, you will probably get the warning anyhow, as I believe the information about open matlab pools is stored in a hidden folder in your home. Rebooting will probably not help, but finding those files and removing them will (be careful though and ask the system administrator).

Comment: So if the process is left running when does it get terminated, if ever? Does it require rebooting the node? And still-running instances of Matlab be causing the warning message I'm getting about pre-existing jobs?

Answer (score 0):

to avoid your warning, you have to delete

.matlab/local_cluster_jobs/

directory